# get_post_meta() to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have a generated data from get_post_meta which I need to convert it to JSON. The generated array are as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rate] => 5
                            [review] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => Test Review
                                    [custom_field_1] => Azman Ishak
                                    [custom_field_2] => Selagnor
                                    [date] =>  2017-06-06  , 15:06 
                                    [title] => 
                                    [status] => publish
                                    [weight] => 5
                                )

                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => ebeneadmin
                                    [email] => azman@considerdigital.com
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [ip] => 115.135.10.5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [rate] => 4
                            [review] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => Test review 2
                                    [custom_field_1] => Azman
                                    [custom_field_2] => Beranang
                                    [date] =>  2017-06-06  , 16:01 
                                    [title] => 
                                    [status] => publish
                                    [weight] => 5
                                )

                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Azman Ishak
                                    [email] => azmunk@gmail.com
                                    [id] => 
                                    [ip] => 115.135.10.5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

The value that I need to get from the above arrays are:

1. rate
2. content
3. custom_field_1
4. custom_field_2
5. date
6. title
7. status

This data need to be converted into JSON.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to code for you. So, since you have been stuck for 2 days, show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and I'm sure you'll get help. This way you can learn from your mistakes and you're not going to do a simply copy+paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

convert your get_post_meta result with [json_encode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

it will make your result to be

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```